# Unable to add lambda target in scheduled rule in AWS cloudwatch

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm Actually Creating a Sheduled Rule in aws cloudwatch in .net as lambda target but im unable to add my lambda as a target.

what is wrong here

```
   `var region = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("us-east-2");`
        `AmazonCloudWatchEventsClient client = new AmazonCloudWatchEventsClient(region);`
        `AmazonLambdaClient lambda = new AmazonLambdaClient();`
        `var putRuleRequest = new PutRuleRequest`
        `{`
           ` Name = "Rule1check",`
            `ScheduleExpression = "cron(0 11 24 * ? 2020)",`
            `State = RuleState.ENABLED,`

        `};`
        `//var putTargetRequest =  "EC2 RebootInstances API call`
        `var putRuleResponse = client.PutRuleAsync(putRuleRequest);`
        `AddPermissionRequest lambdaparam = new AddPermissionRequest`
        `{`
           ` Action = "lambda:InvokeFunction",`
            `FunctionName = "stop_ec2",`
            `Principal = "events.amazonaws.com",`
            `SourceArn = putRuleResponse.ToString(),`
            `StatementId = "ID-1"`
        `};`
       `lambda.AddPermissionAsync(lambdaparam);`
        `var putTargetRequest = new PutTargetsRequest`
       ` {`
            `Rule = "Rule1check",`
            `Targets =`
            `{`
                `new Target { Arn = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:394451858625:function:stop_ec2",` 
                    `Id = "myCloudWatchEventsTarget",`
                    `Input = "{\"region\": \"us-east-2\",\"instances\": \"*******\"}"`
               ` }`
               ` }`
            `};`
        `client.PutTargetsAsync(putTargetRequest);`
```

Comment: Please add more details about your problem, you can see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems here.

1. `SourceArn = putRuleResponse.ToString()`. The `PutRuleResponse` object contains a `RuleArn` property. That's what you should use. `SourceArn = putRuleResponse.RuleArn`.
2. `client.PutRuleAsync(putRuleRequest)` is an `async` call, but you aren't `await`ing it. As a result you are getting a `Task<PutRuleResponse>` back, not a `PutRuleResponse`, and you're getting it before the operation is likely completed.
3. You aren't `await`ing anything, which could be an issue when doing things with dependencies.

Comment: Hi,but i dont have a rule arn property

Comment: That's because you aren't doing an `await` on the call (see the second point). So the object you get back is a `Task<PutRuleResponse>`. If you add an `await` you will get a `PutRuleResponse`.